# Mailto with subject not working

Tags: mailto, squarespace

I am building a site in Squarespace. I am trying to add a mailto: link with a subject.
Here's the code I used: `mailto:email@myemail.com?subject=Website`.

In Firefox and IE, clicking it opens a totally blank new tab. In Chrome, it opens up a blank new tag with the mailto code in the browser window. But the desired behavior is of course to have it open a mail client.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you can control this. `mailto:` depends on the user's desktop configuration.

They may have it open in a mail client, gmail or whatever their configuration is. You can't control how the `mailto:` works.